# add certain string before every 2 characters

Tags: text-processing

I have the following string:

```
AAAACE21
```

I would like to convert it to: `\xAA\xAA\xCE\x21`
Basically I want to add `\x` at the beginning of every 2 characters.
For some reason it seems that whenever I try to loop through the string and add, the `\` doesn't end up there. Is there any one liner that will do the trick?

Comment: In case the intention is to further transform those `\xAA` into the character with byte value `0xaa`, you can do it directly with `perl -pe 's/../chr hex $&/ge'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ echo AAAACE21 | sed 's/../\\x&/g'
\xAA\xAA\xCE\x21
```

In `sed`, **`.`** means any character, so **`..`** matches two characters. 
You often need to type `\\` to get a `\`,
and `&` means replace with what was matched.

The `g` stands for **g**lobal;
i.e., do it as much as possible, wherever possible. 
Without it, you’d get only the first two characters:

```
$ echo AAAACE21 | sed 's/../\\x&/'
\xAAAACE21
```

Comment: what is the g for?

Comment: @John: global replacement (i.e., continue replacing every two characters rather than stopping after the first match)

Comment: Technically, I beat you by six seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using awk:

```
awk -v FS='' '{for(i=1;i<NF;i+=2) printf "\\x%s%s",$i,$(i+1)}END{printf "\n"}' <<<"AAAACE21"
\xAA\xAA\xCE\x21
```

Set the field separator (`FS`) to an empty string to delimit character-wise. Then print every two characters preceded by the desired string. To print a literal backslash, escape it with a backslash.

Comment: Notes: that empty FS behaviour is a GNU extension not supported by all awk implementations though. `<<<` is a zsh extension not supported by all shells. The absence of `;` or newline between `}` and END is also not POSIX but in that case I'm not aware of any modern implementation that doesn't support it.